# Image not working while converting html to pdf

Tags: django, django-views, pisa

I want to convert one html page into pdf in django web- framework , everthing is working good except image .

Here is small snippet of HTML page which I want  to convert into pdf

```
<div class="certi-description"> <img src="/media/certificate/icons/2.jpg" style="width: 12%;height: 25%;position: absolute; left: {{tag_logo_offset.0|add:'-355'}}px; top: {{tag_logo_offset.1|add:'-170'}}px;"><br>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: {{tag_name_offset.0|add:'-355'}}px; top: {{tag_name_offset.1|add:'-170'}}px;"><div id="tag" ><center><font size="3" color="red">{{  tag_name}}</font><center></div></div><br><br>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: {{comm_offset.0|add:'-355'}}px; top: {{comm_offset.1|add:'-170'}}px;"><span><font size="5" color="black">is hereby Rewarded to</font></span></div><br>
```

Here is code snippet in views.py

```
            template = certi.generic_certificate.template_name
            template_new = get_template(template)
            context_dict = Context(context)
            html  = template_new.render(context_dict)
            print html
            result = StringIO.StringIO()
            links = lambda uri, rel: os.path.join(base.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(base.MEDIA_ROOT, ''))
            print  base.MEDIA_ROOT
            pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")),dest=result, link_callback=links)
            if not pdf.err:
                converted_pdf= HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
                converted_pdf['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="certificate%s.pdf"'%certi_id
                p = canvas.Canvas(converted_pdf)
                p.showPage()
                p.save()
                pdf = result.getvalue()
                result.close()
                myfile = ContentFile(pdf)
                Certificate.objects.filter(pk=certi_id).update(pdf_template = p)
                converted_pdf.write(pdf) 
                return converted_pdf
```

base.py as my settings file :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'media'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
########## END MEDIA CONFIGURATION
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('custom.backends.EmailOrUsernameModelBackend',)

########## STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(DJANGO_ROOT, 'final_static'))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have several images in /media/certificate/icons folder like 2.jpg which I am using in my html

Everthing is converting to pdf except image. I have checked all possible paths but still not working.

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: How about using `http://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-python/` ?

Comment: Its not free .  Need to purchage to get :"username" and  "apikey"

Comment: Damn . Try this `https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf` :)

Comment: Yeah , I have tried this one also but it was also causing some problem in returning response

Comment: Above everything is working except image

Comment: try without adding styles . then add styles one by one to img tag . may be some styles don't support it.

Comment: Nopes , Still not working .....Please check Have I used path correctly .

Comment: Starts working .....I have modidied links in above views :  links = lambda uri, rel: os.path.join(base.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(base.MEDIA_URL, ''))

Comment: @Priyank :  But without using style tag as you have said , now how I should I add  style to image?

Comment: aah !!!! nice . Don't know about styles .you can find `custom filters` to add inline styles of django template. try it.

Comment: Hey! on Adding inline styles in html causing problem to load image(invisble from pdf)   .   This is not working : <img src="/media/certificate/icons/3.jpg" style="width:200px;height:200px;">

Comment: I think you already had wasted more time in this library . try different instead . you will find better. :)

Comment: @Hey priyank, Now everything is working good, Image , css everything is  coming in PDF using this pisa documentation.   Now problem is :To fix image position.